# i.MX8 problem: why core M4 periodicly slowly?

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller

I try SOM on i.MX8, but has problem: M4 core periodic change performance.

In ours task  we programm M4 to generate signal diagramm (by GPIO, inside timer handler).
On power on, all is OK.
But after Linux loaded to command prompt, I see that diagramm from M4 now more lenght, as if M4 slowly. Lenght increase to 4 times (see photos)
[image: normal diagramm]
[image: slowly diagramm]

Also I try  NXP samples (driver_examples\gpt), and add to timer handler the simple code, for check performance:

```
int summ = 0 , t1 , t2 ;
/ **********  Code ***** /
void EXAMPLE_GPT_IRQHandler ( void ) {
/ * Clear interrupt flag . * /
GPT_ClearStatusFlags ( EXAMPLE_GPT , KGPT_Output Compare1Flag ) ;
t1 = GPT_GetCurrentTimerCount ( EXAMPLE_GPT ) ;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1; i ++ ) { summ + = i ; } // dummy loop
t2 = GPT GetCurrentTimerCount ( EXAMPLE_GPT ) ;
PRINTF ( " time = % d \ n \ r " , t2 - t1 ) ;
/ **************** /
```

After run, we see that a time the dummy loop is unstable too, like two different "stable" states , about 10 or about 40 (on power on about 10; after load Linux - about 40, but sometimes show 10 again)

Plaese, help me for solve this problem. (sorry for my english)

Comment: I, for one, have no idea what you are trying to ask. Please look at [ask], and grammar-proof your question. If English is not your main language  we understand, but please make an effort to build syntactically easy phrases.

Comment: Also, not many people here are going to open a link to a random google drive link. If you **really** can't describe your problem with just words, maybe use a more trusted platform like youtube.

Comment: Do you think perhaps pictures of your scope display would be more useful than pictures of your entire workbench.  Also, that scope clearly has a USB interface and can no doubt write image files directly rather than photographing it?!

Comment: The code fragment is unreadable has invalid comment delimiters.  It needs correct formatting.

Comment: Do you really mean "unstable"? It sounds more like two different "stable" states to me.

Comment: Nothing is preventing the compiler from removing the whole loop. I would be surprised if it didn't. So either you are benchmarking non-optimized code or you are benchmarking the inaccuracy of your own benchmarking. Neither makes sense. And obviously, calling printf inside an ISR will kill anything ever remotely close to real-time performance in the whole application.

Comment: I'm not an expert re i.MX. But if you run Linux on it, I would expect it will throttle the clock anytime it thinks there is no work to do. Are you sure your low-level programming approach and your expectations about it are valid for a system running Linux?

Comment: @Codo  It is multi-core - I doubt Linux is running on the M4, but the question lacks essential detail IMO.

Comment: @Clifford Linux is explicitly mentioned and shown in the images (and the original video). So my understanding is the i.MX8 runs Linux. If it does, it will throttle all cores. Multi-core will make no difference. But then again, I might misunderstand the setup.

Comment: @Codo Yes, but I would assume that is running on the Cortex-A core(s), not the M4 core(s) since that is already running the code shown, not Linux.  It is normal with ARM big-little architecture to run real-time (i.e. not Linux) code on the MCU core and a GPOS on the application processor core. It is essentially multiple processors on one die, rather than multi-core processor.

Comment: @codo Like this https://www.nxp.com/assets/images/en/block-diagrams/iMX8-Fam-BD-NEW.svg.  As you can see with 256K SRAM and no MMU, the M4 cores are not running Linux.

Comment: No, Linux run on main core Cortex-A53, and on M4 I run my programm

Comment: NXP community forum is a better way for this question, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question in the following way: You are running a program containing the given code snipped on an M4 core of an I.MX8 system on chip. The program creates a PWM signal by utilizing a general purpose timer. (The system on chip also contains a larger ARM core capable of running linux.)

When only the program within the M4 core runs, then the desired waveform timing is achieved. As soon as you boot linux on the other core, the waveform of the PWM seems to change periodically. It changes from the original waveform to the same waveform, but with a frequency drop of factor 4.

---

It seems that linux performs *CPU Frequency Scaling* and/or uses *Dynamic Bus Frequencies*. This may change the frequency of the clock domain of the M4 clock or at least the clock domain of the general purpose timer used to create the PWM. I think, the latter is the relevant problem origin.

See [I.MX Reference Manual](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/i.MX_Reference_Manual_Linux.pdf) sections 2.3.3 and 2.3.4. This manual also lists the following command in order to disable *Dynamic Bus Frequencies* from userspace. (Make sure you are the root user.):

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/busfreq/enable
```

This should stop periodic changes of your waveform.

Comment: Great, Alexandr! Your solution solved problem!
Very thanks!!!!